# How do I make Lumen to use default validation messages?

Tags: lumen

I have a standard folder for error messages in Lumen which is similar to Laravel. The problem is that the messages from there are not used. How can I make Lumen to format messages using my translations?

Right now when I dump $validator->errors() it does not format the messages.

```
MessageBag {#223
  #messages: array:4 [
    "surname" => array:1 [
      0 => "validation.required"
    ]
    "mobile" => array:1 [
      0 => "validation.required"
    ]
    "password" => array:1 [
      0 => "validation.min.string"
    ]
    "email" => array:1 [
      0 => "validation.email"
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

Comment: What language are you using for your application?

Comment: @Alfa I am using English

Comment: Would you mind to share your folder structure? I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: @Alfa I use this project and added lang files - https://github.com/krisanalfa/lumen-jwt

Comment: @Alfa I did find that the app.php config did not have locale set, which cause the trouble. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. You can post an anser I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @Alfa man, its' your package ;D. How could you miss that?

Comment: Yep xD Well, I must be too tired or sleepy back then. Anyway thanks for reporting this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically `translator` missing locale configuration which should be configured before this instance resolved. Add this to your: `config/app.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Locale Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
| by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
| to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
|
*/
'locale' => env('APP_LOCALE', 'en'),
```

Comment: Mate! Thank you very much! For future readers, please note that should you create a config file in "approot/config/app.php", do remember to include locale. :)